# How to serialize/deserialize spring xml config

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I am going to change ldap config of another program (its called openkm) which includes editing a spring xml file like this:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
<security:ldap-server id="ldapServer"
    url="ldap://192.168.0.6:389/DC=ldap,dc=weyler,dc=local"
    manager-dn="CN=Administrator,cn=users,dc=weyler,dc=local"
    manager-password="password"/>

  <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:ldap-authentication-provider
      server-ref="ldapServer"
      user-search-base="cn=Users"
      user-search-filter="(sAMAccountName={0})"
      group-search-base="cn=Users"
      group-search-filter="(member={0})"
      group-role-attribute="cn"
      role-prefix="none">
    </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
  </security:authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

The configuration just concerns to replace existing values (for example to change ip, port or baseDn).
Using replace all with regex is not reliable and Dom xml parser is a mess for this big xml file. How else could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` to externalize these configurations into a property file and access the same from your XML. An example [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/).

And then you can update your property file programmetically with apache common properties or any other property writer.

This way it will be far efficient and cleaner than to manipulate XMLs.

Comment: its not my xml, its some other program config file which i should configure programaticaly. although the guys in openkm should have consider using property file instead of spring xml files for config their program!

Comment: In that case you have no option than to use a XML parser. If you find DOM parser API is hard, JDOM would be a good choice. However if the file is very large and efficiency is a concern you may try StAX parser.

Comment: jaxb would have been an option if i only knew about that spring xml config classes

Comment: JAXB won't be an option unless the spring source files have been annotated with JAXB. However you may consider  writing a BeanFactoryPostProcessor along the lines of http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer.

Comment: Thanks, finally i end up with a dirty/but-simple idea of replacing with preconfigured xml config using placeholders, because the xml file content would not change so often